# Understanding the execution order of subsequent then() handlers of an resolved promise

Tags: javascript, callstack, event-loop

I am learning Promise, in order to understand it I read a bit about Event loop of JavaScript. This [article](http://altitudelabs.com/blog/what-is-the-javascript-event-loop/) briefly introduced the working of event loop such as call stack, event table and message queue.

But I don't know how the call stack deal with the line containing 'return', and what happens thereafter.
Below is an example that I wrote to hopefully understand how Promise works based on event loop. Also see http://jsbin.com/puqogulani/edit?js,console if you want to give it a go.

```
var p1 = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(0);
});

p1.then(function(val){
  console.log(val);
  p1.then(function(){
    console.log("1.1.1");
    p1.then(function(){
      console.log("1.1.2");
      p1.then(function(){
        console.log("1.1.3");
      });
    });
  });

  p1.then(function(){
    console.log("1.2");
  })

  return 30;

  //return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  //  resolve(30);
  //});

})
  .then(function(val){
  console.log(val/2);
});

p1.then(function(){
  console.log("2.1");
});

console.log("Start");
```

As can be seen, there are two "return", using each of them will give a different output order. Specifically, when using `return 30;`, `1.1.2, 1.1.3` are after `15`, but when using `return new Promise(...)`, `1.1.2, 1.1.3` are before `15`. So what exactly happened when the code reached two different 'return'?

Comment: Removed the callbacks of 1.1.4 and 1.1.5 - they're not referred to and make it not easier to understand and everyone gets the point up to 1.1.2 already. Everyone will still be able to understand the dilemma without them.

Comment: @try-catch-finally, Thanks for your suggestion and editing. I just wanted to make it clearer, though sometimes it makes the opposite :)

Comment: So @try-catch-finally, I am wondering if you could give advices on my question? Thank you

Comment: I was trying to reduce that example to a bare minimum, predicting the behavior, testing it and building it up step by step. I don't feel 100% confident to give you a useful answer. But I'd say it's because an already resolved Promise will call its handlers synchronously (that is the call of `p1.then()` within its very first handler - though it was resolved async, initially, now the remaining handlers will be called sync) while a Promise is always resolved async thus giving the stack established in `p1` time to finish calling the handlers. General advice: don't `p1.then()` inside `p1.then()` :/

Comment: http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html and https://bevacqua.github.io/promisees/

Comment: @coma, Thanks for your reply. I'll watch the video you mentioned later, but the visualisation you advised is really obvious and acceptable, very nice, thank you!

Comment: @try-catch-finally, do you mean returning a new Promise is async so that it takes more time than returning an existed value like '30', thus caused '15' show up later than ''1.1.3"? Besides, would you mind explaining more how many steps are needed for call stack and event table to process "return new Promise(...)"? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is described in http://promisesaplus.com/ under the promise resolution procedure.

For the first return value:

> 2.3.3.4 If then is not a function, fulfill promise with x.

For the second:

> 2.3.2 If x is a promise, adopt its state [3.4]:
>
> 2.3.2.2 If/when x is fulfilled, fulfill promise with the same value.

We can see this implemented [q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js). This is one possible implementation but seems to explain the delay:

```
function coerce(promise) {
    var deferred = defer();
    Q.nextTick(function () {
        try {
            promise.then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, deferred.notify);
        } catch (exception) {
            deferred.reject(exception);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When returning a promise from the `then` function, we have two separate promise objects: the one returned from the function passed to `then`, and the one returned from `then`. These need to be connected together so that resolving the first, resolves the second. This is done with `promise.then(deferred.resolve, ...)`

The first delay comes from `Q.nextTick`. This executes the function on the next iteration of the event loop. There's some discussion in the [commit comments](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/commit/3f32632c7a2113a7c4604dfcf46d1265beacc493) on why it's needed.

Calling `promise.then` adds a further delay of one iteration of the event loop. As required in the spec:

> 2.2.4 onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code. [3.1].

The execution would go something like:

```
p1.then with function containing 1.1.1 is called
    function containing 1.1.1 is queued
p1.then with function containing 1.2 is called
    function containing 1.2 is queued
Promise resolving to 30 is returned
    Q.nextTick function is queued
----------
1.1.1 is printed
p1.then with function containing 1.1.2 is called
    function containing 1.1.2 is queued
1.2 is printed
Q.nextTick function is executed
    promise.then(deferred.resolve, ...) is queued
----------
1.1.2 is printed
p1.then with function containing 1.1.3 is called
    function containing 1.1.3 is queued
promise.then(deferred.resolve, ...) is executed
    function containing val/2 is queued
----------
1.1.3 is printed
val/2 is printed
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your article that is very clearly stating what I want to know!