# How is a Promise That Is Returned From A Resolve Handler Mapped To The Return Value of 'then'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

If I'm chaining Promises and I return a Promise from the resolve handler, how does that Promise become the return value of the call to `then`? What is going on behind the scenes?

In the following example, in `firstMethodHandler`, the call to `secondMethod`receives a new Promise which it then returns, but that promise is then returned from the `then` method in which it is passed to its promise. How does this happen?

```
function firstMethod(value) {
  console.log('1st method:', value)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(++value);
  });
}

function secondMethod(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('2nd method:', value)
    resolve(++value);
  });
}

function firstMethodHandler(value) {
  console.log("1st method handler:",value);
  return secondMethod(value);
}

function secondMethodHandler(value) {
  console.log("2nd method handler:", value);
}


firstMethod(1)
  .then(firstMethodHandler)
  .then(secondMethodHandler)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for beyond "that's what the Promise specification says should happen" or "its an implementation detail of the Promise library".

Comment: … or "the same way as any other return value is passed as an argument to another function call"

Comment: Not certain what specific Question is? See also [Are there differences between .then(functionReference) and .then(function(value){return functionReference(value)})?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191131/are-there-differences-between-thenfunctionreference-and-thenfunctionvalue)

Comment: I think the question is about how promise chaining works and how `.then()` handlers fit into the promise chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 From perspective here, OP appears to be querying how the `Promise` value is passed  to function within `.then()` when only a reference to the function is present? Curious if you have reviewed this Question [Understanding the execution order of subsequent then() handlers of an resolved promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788626/understanding-the-execution-order-of-subsequent-then-handlers-of-an-resolved-p) ?

Comment: @guest271314 - I have not reviewed that (I was sleeping when it was posted).  I think some of that question is answered by my answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that `p1.then()` returns a new promise we will call `p2`.  When `p1` is resolved, it calls the `.then()` handler attached to it.  When you return another promise from that `.then()` (which we will call `p3`), then `p3` is chained to `p2` and thus `p2` will not be resolved until `p3` resolves.  So, the caller of the original `p1.then()` will get back a promise `p2` that won't be resolved until both `p1` and `p3` are resolved.  That's how things are chained together.

Usually, the key piece of information here is that `p1.then()` returns a new promise and it is that promise that is affected by what happens inside the previous `.then()` handler.

You can see a similar explanation here:

[Difference between resolve and return in promise JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435034/difference-between-resolve-and-return-in-promise-js/41456446#41456446)

---

In your specific example:

```
firstMethod(1)
  .then(firstMethodHandler)
  .then(secondMethodHandler)
```

`firstMethod()` returns a promise I will call `p1`.  Then, calling `.then(firstMethodHandler)` on that promise returns a new promise `p2` and then calling `.then(secondMethodHandler)` on that creates a new promise `p3`.

At some point in the future, `firstMethod()` resolves the promise it returned.  So, now `p1` is resolved.  That calls the `.then()` handler attached to it and thus calls `firstMethodHandler()`.  That returns a new promise `p4`. That chains `p4` to the `p2` promise so `p2` will not resolve until `p4` does.  At some point in the future, `p4` resolves which allows `p2` to resolve. That calls the `.then()` handler attached to `p2` which thus calls `secondMethodHandler()` and you see the final `console.log()`.

As you can see from the explanation, the key here is the new promises `p2` and `p3` that are created when `.then()` is first executed. That's what the chained `.then()` handlers are actually linked to and those promises are what are influenced by what is returned from the attached `.then()` handlers.

To see what the chaining is doing, we can remove the actual chaining and show you the actual intermediate variables that are automatically created and used:

```
var p1 = firstMethod(1);
var p2 = p1.then(firstMethodHandler);
var p3 = p2.then(secondMethodHandler);
```

`p1` is resolved internal to `firstMethod()`
`p2` is the return value of `p1.then(...)`
`p3` is the return value of `p2.then(...)`

When `firstMethodHandler` is called (after p1 resolves), then it returns `p4` which is chained to `p2` so that `p2` does not resolved until `p4` resolves.  When `p4` finally resolves, it allows `p2` to resolve which then calls `secondMethodHandler`.  When that `.then()` handler returns a normal value, then `p3` is resolved and the whole chain is done.

Comment: You say 'When you return another promise from that .then()' but this is exactly my question. I don't return a promise from then(). I return it from the function/handler that I passed in to then(). How does this promise end up being returned from then()?  I interested in that mechanism.

Comment: @Pedr - Every call to `.then()` returns a new promise.  The return value of `.then()` is a new promise.  That's not something you do.  That's how `.then()` works.  Remember all the calls to `.then()` on the chain are executed immediately and their promises are created immediately.  The callbacks passed to `.then()` are registered as event handlers internally so they can be called later.  Please read the last four paragraphs of my answer.  That shows you all the intermediate promises that are created automatically for you.

Comment: Thankyou. I think the penny just dropped. I understood that the promise I was returning from the callback was the same promise returned from  the call to `then()`, but of course that isn't possible as the `then()` has already returned. I'll pick through your answer and hopefully put my head to bed.

Comment: @Pedr - Yeah, the promises are linked so that resolving one down the chain causes the original one returned far up the chain to eventually get resolved which is what the caller actually sees.  It is a bit confusing.  Eventually, you just get how the chaining concept works and can just use it without having to make your brain hurt trying to figure out how the chaining is actually implemented.